# QR code reader Android other than zxing

Tags: android, qr-code

I need to implement a QR code reader inside my app. I have gone across zxing, but i find it a little bit intimidating. Also I need it inside my app. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

ZBar bar code reader here http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/?source=dlp

it's much faster than zxing and much easier to implement.

Alternatively

There are no need to install zxing for implementing qr reader, 
Just create a class IntentIntegrator.java and IntentResult.java file and call from your activity.

Hear source code this....
https://code.google.com/p/dwivedi-ji-qr-code-reader/source/checkout

Answer (score 0):

try zbar very easy to implement.use this for reference

https://github.com/DushyanthMaguluru/ZBarScanner